# Distinct meanings of "neanche"

Tags: meaning

"Neanche" has distinct meanings:

- either/neither. Ex:

  - A: I don't want his money.
  - B: I don't want it either / Me neither.
- even. Ex:

  - A: You need to work hard in order to get this promotion.
  - B: I don't even want it.
- not even. Ex: Not even Usain Bolt would run so fast.

Can the intended meaning be deduced from word position or only from context? Example:

- Neanche io sono un bravo studente.  (= "Not even I am a good student" or "I am not a good student either" ?)
- Non sono neanche un bravo studente ( = "I am not even a good student" or "I am not a good student either" ? )

Answer (score 4):

You're right that the meaning can be inferred from the position; *neanche* requires an explicit or implicit referent.

In *neanch'io sono un bravo studente* the referent is some other person who is or claims to be a not so good student. In *non sono neanche un bravo studente* the referent is some other quality the speaker lacks or claims to lack.

The first sentence can also be *non sono un bravo studente neanch'io*, with the same meaning.

The second sentence could be rendered in English with *either* or *not even*, depending on the context. The ambiguity would be in English if *either* is used, not in Italian.

Comment: Could the first sentence be rendered in English with "either" or "not even" too, as I suggested in my question?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Depending on context, perhaps; probably something like “dopo tutto” would be added (or implied), in this case.